# Restfull api Yii2 + apache Дольгий ответ локального сервера

Tags: php, yii2, apache2, rest

Есть фронтенд на ExtJS есть бэкенд (RESTFULL API) на yii2. Но дело даже не во фронте... В общем делаем GET запрос на бекенд и ответ приходит только через 1,5 секунды.

[image: пример]
В первой строчке запрос OPTION. все оптион у меня сразу перенаправляются в конкретный контроллер в конкретный экшн, собственно там возвращаются только заголовки. т.к. фронт и бэк работают на разных виртуальных хостах, но оба на локальном сервере. И учитывая факт возврата пустого заголовка 500 ms это много.. Следующий запрос непосредственно получет информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скринах там всего 2 строки возвращается и вес страницы минимальный. Но на это тратится 1.5 секунды времени. На каждый запрос.

Я продебажыл код самыми различными способами начиная от микротайм на php,

Yii2 debugger

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот тут видно что 1.2 секунды, и видно что запросы к бд заняли всего 12 ms на что потрачено остальное время не понятно.

и xdebug
результат отработки скрипта в районе 200 ms

Пробывал оптимизировать апач сервер вот по этой статье
[https://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/05/27/оптимизация-производительности-apache/](https://ruhighload.com/index.php/2009/05/27/%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-apache/)
Но ни чего не изменилось. Правда мне пришлось оставить prefork mpm. тк апач ругался на пхп (его нужно перекомпилировать если ставишь другой модуль mpm).

Apache 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Php [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в какую сторону копать? может уже кто то сталкивался с таким?

PS. еще есть проект c бэкендом на phalcon. Там запросы отдаются 300-400 ms

Comment: Собственно сегодня, по воле случая мне пришлось свичнуться на php56 что бы кое что исправить в старых проектах. И собственно на php56 это все дело работает безумно быстро 127 -150 мс ответ... Но стоило переключится обратно на php71 - снова скорость ответов 1.5 секунды. Что не так с пхп71?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!

Дело было в старой версии Yii2 фреймворка. Обновил через композер теперь на 7 пхп отдаются теже запросы за 58 мс